# HDD starts spinning every so often even though it's not accessible

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

So I've decided to make my PC more quiet by shutting down my HDD which is only used for storage I don't often access. With powershell, I made a script to set my HDD as offline and put it to sleep:

```
Set-Disk -Number 0 -IsOffline $True
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\hdparm\hdparm.exe" @("-Y", "/dev/sda")
```

This works. The drive is set to offline and it stops spinning.

Now, even though I can't access it anymore, my HDD awakes every ~15-30 minutes until it's being put to sleep again due to inactivity.
It seems like there's still something else waking the HDD up. Any ideas?